# Rewriting char array with filter using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I need to rewrite an array of chars but filtering out characters I dont want. So for example array: "abcdefgabcdefg", filter "abc", result: "abcabc". I need to use pointers. So far i came up with this without any success:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char * function(char *d, char *z, char *filter){
    int x = strlen(z) + 1; int y = strlen(filter) + 1; bool b = false;
    for( ; *z ; z++, d++){
        for( ; *filter ; filter++){
            if(*z == *filter)
                b = true;
        }
        if(b)
            *d=*z;
        b = false;
        filter-=y;
    }
    return d;
}

int main(){
    char d[80];
    cout << function(d, "abbccddeeefa", "abd");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question exactly? StackOverflow is not a debugging service

Comment: You increment `d` in the outer loop whether or not you actually stored the current character (`*z`) in it. And, `filter-=y` makes absolutely no sense whatsoever, and causes your program to read a wild pointer and exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: You may want to reduce pointer issues by using `std::string`.  Pass by reference if you modify the parameter; constant reference otherwise.

Comment: Why do you need to use pointers? Unnecessarily using pointers instead of C++ standard library classes like `std::string` is the cause of many problems like the one you're having right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not managing your pointers correctly.

You are incrementing your output pointer regardless of whether you write anything to it.

And you are decrementing your filter pointer too much when you try to reset it back to its first character after looping to its null terminator.

And there is no need to waste time and processing power to call `strlen()` at all.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char* function(char *buffer, const char *str, const char *filter) {
    char *b = buffer;
    for (; *str; ++str) {
        char ch = *str;
        for(const char *f = filter; *f; ++f) {
            if (ch == *f) {
                *b++ = ch;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    *b = '\0';
    return buffer;
}

int main(){
    char d[80];
    cout << function(d, "abbccddeeefa", "abd");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```